# anytime i press an <a> tags the menu opens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tags

i have this html and javascript for my menu button

THIS IS THE HTML

MENU

```
<div class="mobilenav"> 
  <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">WORK</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">TALK</a></li> 
</div>
```

ICON

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="icon"> 
  <div class="MENU"> 
    <div class="menui top-menu"></div> 
    <div class="menui mid-menu"></div> 
    <div class="menui bottom-menu"></div> 
  </div> 
</a>
```

AND JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".icon").click(function () {
    $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(500);
    $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
    $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
    $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate");
  });
});
```

i changed the ".icon" for an "a" so the menu closes as soon as i picked any option, now anytime i clicked on the scroll down button, contact and any other  tag button the menu opens, is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: It will be easier for us, if you provide your code in jsFiddle.net

Comment: isn't `.icon` class working..??

Comment: A note: if you have `href="javascript:void(0)"` for an `a` and clicking that  `a` will only trigger some visual effect, then you most likely should not use an `a` there. Is there a reason why you don't use a `div`?

Comment: i don't know how to use it and i'm really desperate, i need to deliver this work in about 6 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("a")` selects all links on the page.

Instead you only want the select `.icon` + the links in the `.mobilenav`, so you need to do `$(".icon, .mobilenav a")`.

Note that JQuery selectors work almost the same as [CSS selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".icon, .mobilenav a").click(function () {
    $(".mobilenav").fadeToggle(500);
    $(".top-menu").toggleClass("top-animate");
    $(".mid-menu").toggleClass("mid-animate");
    $(".bottom-menu").toggleClass("bottom-animate");
  });
});
```

Comment: and it will still close the menu as soon as i choose an item?

Comment: ok, i've just tried it and you sir, are a life savior, my offsprings will sing song about your heroic deed (no sarcasm)